Nesting React Native Expo Scrollview One for vertical and on for horizontal not working as expected
I am trying to create two React Native Views one which scrolls vertically and one inside that one which scrolls a svg d3 graph horizontally. For the inner horizontal scrolling I am seeing a graph which is cut short horizonatlly and is not scrollable.  Here is my code:
<ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
    {graphLoaded &&
        {loadingIcon &&
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
          }
        <ScrollView style={styles.healthSpanGraph} horizontal={true} >
            <Svg id="graphLandingPage" width='0%' height='0%'>
            </Svg>
        </ScrollView>
        <DataTable style={styles.container}>
        <DataTable.Header style={styles.tableHeader}>
          <DataTable.Title style={styles.tableColumn}>Disease Name</DataTable.Title>
          <DataTable.Title style={styles.tableColumn}>Action</DataTable.Title>
          <DataTable.Title style={styles.tableColumn}>Action</DataTable.Title>
          <DataTable.Title style={styles.tableColumn}>View</DataTable.Title>
        </DataTable.Header>
            {graphs.slice(
                page * numberOfItemsPerPage,
                page * numberOfItemsPerPage + numberOfItemsPerPage
              ).map((item) => (
                <DataTable.Row key={item.id} style={selectedGraphs[item.id]?[styles.tableRow, styles.tableSelectedColor]:styles.tableRow} onPress={()=>highlightGraph(item.id)}>
                  <DataTable.Cell style={styles.tableColumn}>{item.diseaseName}</DataTable.Cell>
                   <DataTable.Cell style={styles.tableColumn} numeric>
                      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("UpdateUserGraphWeb",
                      { id: item.id, diseaseId: item.userDiseaseId, diseaseName: item.diseaseName, userId: item.userId})}>
                          <Text style={styles.actionText}>Update Graph</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                  </DataTable.Cell>
                  <DataTable.Cell style={styles.tableColumn} numeric>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("DeleteUserGraphModalWeb", { id: item.id})}>
                            <Text style={styles.actionText}>Delete Graph</Text>
                          </TouchableOpacity>
                    </DataTable.Cell>
                    <DataTable.Cell style={styles.tableColumn} numeric>
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("PatientGraphLandingPageWeb", { id: item.id})}>
                                <Text style={styles.actionText}>View Graph</Text>
                              </TouchableOpacity>
                        </DataTable.Cell>
                </DataTable.Row>
              ))}
              <DataTable.Pagination
                 page={page}
                 numberOfPages={Math.ceil(graphs.length / numberOfItemsPerPage)}
                 onPageChange={(page) => changePage(page)}
                 label={`${from + 1}-${to} of ${graphs.length}`}
                 showFastPaginationControls
                 numberOfItemsPerPage={numberOfItemsPerPage}
               />
      </DataTable>
    </ScrollView>

And my stylings:
container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection:'column',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
    scrollView: {
        marginHorizontal: 0,
        height: 500,
    },
    healthSpanGraph: {
        marginHorizontal: 0,
        width: wp(100)
    },
 tableHeader: {
    backgroundColor: '#2196F3',
    color: 'black',
    width: Platform.OS === 'web' ? wp(100) : wp(80),
    marginTop: (isSafari === true || iOSSafari === true) ? 70 : 0
  },
  tableRow: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    color: 'black',
    width: Platform.OS === 'web' ? wp(100) : wp(80)
  }

If I remove the inner ScrollView The graph appears as normal but with it the graph appears cropped horizontally.
